# How to use GetProcessMemoryInfo in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management

I'm trying to use the function `GetProcessMemoryInfo` of `psapi.h` inside a C++ application on Windows 7 32-bit.

I followed some tutorial and I did something like:

```
PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pMemCountr;

pMemCountr = new PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS();
bool result = GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(),
                                   pMemCountr,
                                   sizeof(PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS));
```

The problem is that i always obtain "false" from the execution of the `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` method. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try calling `GetLastError` after that, to get more information on the cause of the error

Comment: what does GetLastError() retuns?

Comment: A relatively simple question with a simple answer, but still well-asked. Better than a lot of what I see around here, so a +1 from me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is

```
sizeof(PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS)
```

yields the size of `PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS` which is a `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*` type pointer (note double `P` in the beginning).

What you want is

```
sizeof(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS)
```

Also you'll be much better off without `new` here:

```
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS memCounter;
BOOL result = GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(),
                                   &memCounter,
                                   sizeof( memCounter ));
```

Comment: A good reason why you should always use the name of the variable as the argument to the `sizeof` operator, rather than the type name.

Comment: @CodyGray: that's not true. You just need to understand what you put into your `sizeof` operator. Putting the pointer address or the `PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS` type will return the pointer size, which is 4 bytes on a x86 system. Putting the object pointed at this address or the `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS` type will return the actual object size. Neither is *always* the good solution.

Comment: I get the performance warning 4800 `forcing value to bool`, do you know how to fix it? which variable could be a BOOL?

Comment: @quimnuss Function returns `BOOL` which is an integer, that's what the compier is trying to say. I fixed the code.

Comment: Wow, bravo Microsoft. So `int` would also.be correct (so long as they don't re-typedef it), and error is detected with `if(result == 0) cerr<<"error"<<endl;`, either way.

Comment: @quimnuss It's not "bravo Microsoft", it's the result of designing API which can be called from C (no bool in C). It's better to use `BOOL` and compare it against zero instead of `int`.

Comment: @sharptooth: “no bool in C” – [C has had a boolean type since 1999.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types)

Answer (score 4):

change sizeof(PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS) to sizeof(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS)

Answer (score 3):

On MSDN:

BOOL WINAPI GetProcessMemoryInfo(
  *In*  HANDLE                   Process,
  *Out* PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS ppsmemCounters,
  *In*  DWORD                    cb
);

Example:

```
HANDLE hProcess;
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;

printf( "\nProcess ID: %u\n", processID );

// Print information about the memory usage of the process.
hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID );
if (NULL == hProcess)
    return;

if (GetProcessMemoryInfo( ( hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)))
{
    printf( "\tWorkingSetSize: 0x%08X - %u\n",  pmc.WorkingSetSize,  
                                              pmc.WorkingSetSize / 1024);        
    printf( "\tQuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", 
         pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage ,   pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage / 1024);
    printf( "\tQuotaPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage, 
                                              pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage / 1024);
    printf( "\tQuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", 
               pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage,pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage / 1024 );
    printf( "\tQuotaNonPagedPoolUsage:0x%08X-%u\n",pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage ,   pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage / 1024);
    printf( "\tPagefileUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", pmc.PagefileUsage,     pmc.PagefileUsage/1024 ); 
    printf( "\tPeakPagefileUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", pmc.PeakPagefileUsage, pmc.PeakPagefileUsage/1024 );
    printf( "\tcb: 0x%08X - %u\n", pmc.cb , pmc.cb / 1024);     
}
CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

Or You can view full code from [here](http://learn-tech-tips.blogspot.com/2015/08/get-memory-of-process-with-process-id-by-getprocessmemoryinfo.html)