# Is there a way to measure runtime memory usage of a c++ program?

Tags: c++, memory

Basically I'm doing some competitive programming stuf, and I want to check (locally) how much memory is used by my program during runtime. I would like to measure this using another program. Is there a way to do that? If so, can I have the code? Quite confused here.

Would be better if there's a platform-independent way.

Comment: If there isn't a platform independent way, do you have a platform in mind?

Comment: There's certainly no platform independent way.

Comment: Heaptrack is one way (linux). Another hacky way is to overload `new`, `delete` operators and count of your allocations.

Comment: @Waqar don't forget `malloc` and `free`. I once worked in a project where they overloaded all relevant `new` and `delete` operators, and defined macros for `malloc` and `free`. This mostly worked, except for memory issues due to fragmentation.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler, could you please elaborate a bit on the ``memory fragmentation`` issues? What is the problem if one overloads ``new``/``malloc`` and ``delete``/``free`` ? Don't they behave the same ? When I say ``overload``, I am thinking of just printing to a text file the number of bytes allocated in that particular invocation of ``new``/``malloc``, similarly for free-ing the bytes. At end of the program (or at runtime), do the calculations to see how many bytes are allocated. Thanks (PS: I am refering to something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLlGEUO_EGE)

Comment: @velenos14, memory fragmentation is when you have free memory which isn't contiguous and so can't be used to contain  big objects or vectors. In effect, this memory is lost for your big objects although it is technically free. The amount of fragmentation depends on the allocation algorithm and the sequence of alloc/free. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)

Comment: If you can compile and run your program under MacOS/XCode, their "Instruments" package has a nice heap-usage-monitor tool:  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingPatterns.html

Comment: @MichaelVeksler, I have a vague idea of memory fragmentation. My question was whether this phenomenon is influenced by the overloading of ```new``` and ```delete```, that is: you get more fragmentation if you also print out to the console/file how many bytes you de-allocated? I think not, but then your first comment doesn't make much sense. ```This mostly worked, except for memory issues due to fragmentation``` <--- what this has to do with overloading ? Thanks

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, thanks, I compile on a HPC cluster (Linux) or a WSL2 with Ubuntu in Win11, so no MacOS availability. But good to know

Comment: @velenos14 most likely, overloading new/delete will not change fragmentation in any way. Usually, new/delete use the same algorithm as malloc/free, and so it creates the same fragmentation before and after overloading.  My comment about fragmentation was referring to the accuracy of statistics. Usually, such statistic does not account for fragmentation, and so it is overly optimistic. It is not caused by overloading of new/delete, rather, fragmentation makes the statistics tell only a partial story.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler, I now understand what you meant. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no platform-independent way. If you want to measure memory usage outside the program, without changing its code, then you need to use OS specific tools.

On Linux: [In Linux, how to tell how much memory processes are using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853655/in-linux-how-to-tell-how-much-memory-processes-are-using). It basically tells you to parse `/proc/{the process id of the running program}/smaps`. A variant of this may work on other systems that have a `/proc/` filesystem.

On Windows: [How to use GetProcessMemoryInfo in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644110/how-to-use-getprocessmemoryinfo-in-c). It requires the `HANDLE` of the process, which you can get with

```
handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, 
                     FALSE, process_id);
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS couters;
GetProcessMemoryInfo( handle, &counters, sizeof(counters));
CloseHandle(handle);

now do something with counters ....
```

Edit:

There seems to be a Linux (and possibly Mac/OS) tool, [oi](https://objectintrospection.org/docs/intro), to do just that. Although I have never used it, [its presentation](https://youtu.be/6IlTs8YRne0?si=kg6SXkWSmqPmaIGd) looks quite impressive.